# Invertible matrix if the sum of the absolute values of a column is lower than the absolute of the diagonal value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I've been trying to prove that if I have $A=[a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ therefore, if;

[image]

Then the matrix is invertible.

Can anyone help me and give me some vocabulary (If I'm not wrong, there is a name for this type of matrix, isn't there?)

Comment: It is a [diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove it by contradiction. Assume we have a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax = 0$. This means that $A$ is singular, i.e. non-invertible. This means that for all $k$, we have
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} x_j = 0 \qquad \forall k = 1 \ldots n
\end{equation}
**Let's choose $k=m$, where $\vert x_m \vert$ is the largest amongst all and discuss**
\begin{equation}
 -a_{mm}x_m = \sum_{j \neq m}
 a_{mj} x_j
\end{equation}

i.e.
\begin{equation}
 -a_{mm} = \sum_{j \neq m}
 a_{mj} \frac{x_j}{x_m}
\end{equation}
Take the absolute value on both sides, we get
\begin{equation}
 \vert a_{mm} \vert=
 \Big\vert 
 \sum_{j \neq m}
 a_{mj} \frac{x_j}{x_m}
 \Big\vert 
 \leq
 \sum_{j \neq m}
 \vert a_{mj}\vert  . \Big\vert \frac{x_j}{x_m} \Big\vert 
\end{equation}
But $ \Big\vert \frac{x_j}{x_m} \Big\vert  \leq 1$, so
\begin{equation}
 \vert a_{mm} \vert
 \leq
 \sum_{j \neq k}
 \vert a_{mj} \vert 
\end{equation}
But this is a contradiction of the assumption. Hence, $A$ has to be invertible.

Comment: Are you choosing $k$ to be the index such that $|x_k|$ is maximal?

Comment: Thanks for the note @GregMartin